# Java library to form and parse soap messages

Tags: java, xml, soap

I've tried Axis 2.  It dies when trying to parse my WSDL from Seibel.  I don't want anything that requires a container (Metro).  All I want to do is parse and form SOAP messages.  I don't want them sending the messages on my behalf.  I'm already using HttpClient for that and am happy with it.

Answer (score 3):

Recommend using StAX (Streaming API for XML)

reference: http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaXML/article.html
Sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns:PicklistWS_GetPicklistValues_Output xmlns:ns="urn:crmondemand/ws/picklist/">
      <ListOfParentPicklistValue xmlns="urn:/crmondemand/xml/picklist">
        <ParentPicklistValue>
          <Language>ENU</Language>
          <ParentFieldName/>
          <ParentDisplayValue/>
          <ParentCode/>
          <Disabled/>
          <ListOfPicklistValue>
            <PicklistValue>
              <Code>F</Code>
              <DisplayValue>F</DisplayValue>
              <Disabled>N</Disabled>
            </PicklistValue>
            <PicklistValue>
              <Code>M</Code>
              <DisplayValue>M</DisplayValue>
              <Disabled>N</Disabled>
            </PicklistValue>
          </ListOfPicklistValue>
        </ParentPicklistValue>
      </ListOfParentPicklistValue>
    </ns:PicklistWS_GetPicklistValues_Output>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Parsing Code:

```
static Map<String, String> getPicklistFromSoapResponse(String soapResponse) throws ServiceException {
    Map<String, String> values = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    String code = null;
    String display = null;
    String disabled = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(soapResponse.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        XMLEventReader eventReader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(in);
        while (eventReader.hasNext()) {
            XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();
            if (event.isStartElement()) {
                if (event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart().equals("Code")) {
                    event = eventReader.nextEvent();
                    code = event.asCharacters().getData();
                    continue;
                }
                if (event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart().equals("DisplayValue")) {
                    event = eventReader.nextEvent();
                    display = event.asCharacters().getData();
                    continue;
                }
                if (event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart().equals("Disabled")) {
                    event = eventReader.nextEvent();
                    disabled = event.asCharacters().getData();
                    if ( "Y".equals(disabled)) values.put(code, display);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new ServiceException(e);
    } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
        throw new ServiceException(e);
    }
    return values;
}
```

The line:

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(soapResponse.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

can be switch for a file as the source of the xml with:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("myFile.xml");
```

While looping through the events, the first thing we need to do is get the XMLEvent with `eventReader.nextEvent()`. Normally we only care for events that are start elements, which is retrieved with the line:

```
event.isStartElement()
```

This checks to see if what we are looking at is an opening tag. For example in: `<name>Fenton</name>` only the `<name>` part is the start element. So taking that snippet of xml, calling the following

```
event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart()
```

results in the string: name. To get the string Fenton we call: `event.asCharacters().getData()`

Now sometimes an element will have attributes like: `<name type="User">Fenton</name>`. In this case the part `type="User"` is an attribute and it can be extracted with:

```
StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
Iterator<Attribute> attributes = startElement.getAttributes();
while (attributes.hasNext()) {
    Attribute attribute = attributes.next();
    if (attribute.getName().toString().equals("type"));
    String typeIsUser = attribute.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[SAAJ](https://saaj.dev.java.net/) (SOAP with Attachments API for Java) does that.

But you should consider using a web-service stack rather than manually handling SOAP messages.