# How to extract XML nested tags from Soap object?

Tags: java, android

Here is my requirement,

I am getting response from the server as a soap object, i converted it to string format, now i want to extract the xml data,

How can i extract the nested tags?

Can I extract all the data or do i need to parse that XML response?
Is there any way to extract the XML nested tags and parse it to ArrayList<> Where post is a class?

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <maintag>
    <item>
      <name>AndroidPeople</name> 
      <website category="android">www.androidpeople.com</website> 
    </item>
    <item>
      <name>iPhoneAppDeveloper</name> 
      <website category="iPhone">www.iphone-app-developer.com</website> 
      </item>
    </maintag>
..
```

If possible how?

Thanks in Advance.

i saw this is it possible to use it and how

```
private static Show getShowFromRSS(Context context, Document feed,
        String feedUrl) {
    try {
        // There should be one channel in the feed, get it.
        // Also, the cast should be okay if the XML is formatted correctly
        NodeList item = feed.getElementsByTagName("channel");
        Element el = (Element)item.item(0);

        String title;
        NodeList titleNode = el.getElementsByTagName("title");
        if (titleNode == null || titleNode.getLength() < 1)
            title = context.getString(R.string.default_title);
        else
            title = titleNode.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

        String author;
        NodeList authorNode = el.getElementsByTagName("author");
        if (authorNode == null || authorNode.getLength() < 1)
            author = context.getString(R.string.default_author);
        else
            author = authorNode.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

        String desc;
        NodeList descNode = el.getElementsByTagName("comments");
        if (descNode == null || descNode.getLength() < 1)
            desc = context.getString(R.string.default_comments);
        else
            desc = descNode.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

        String imageUrl;
        NodeList imagNode = el.getElementsByTagName("image");
        if(imagNode != null) {
            Element ima = (Element)imagNode.item(0);
            if (ima != null) {
                NodeList urlNode = ima.getElementsByTagName("url");
                if(urlNode == null || urlNode.getLength() < 1)
                    imageUrl = null;
                else
                    imageUrl =
                        urlNode.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
            } else
                imageUrl = null;
        } else
            imageUrl = null;

        return new Show(title, author, feedUrl, desc, imageUrl, -1, -1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Any parse errors and we'll log and fail
        Log.e("NCRSS", "Error parsing RSS", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need an XML Parser.

Look through this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java

Answer (score 0):

You can use JAXB to marshall/unmarshall the SOAP packets.
I assume you have a schema for the SOAP packets that you have.
Check this out -  [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/).

Comment: You can use that too, but you will have to code the handlers.

Comment: can you provide me with an example please

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your SOAP Object like normal XML, (SAX, etc.) Check out this tutorial:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

With `XPath`:
[Soap response message parsing using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147423/soap-response-message-parsing-using-xpath)

and this: [Java library to form and parse soap messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571764/java-library-to-form-and-parse-soap-messages)

and this: http://www.coderanch.com/t/520979/XML/parse-SOAP-Xml-java-code